# What is the meaning when we say power of circuit having a clock frequency 100Hz is 2W?

Tags: power, digital-logic, clock

When we say clock frequency is 100Hz, then there are 100 clock pulses in one second. So when we say power is 2W, is it 2W for 100 cycles or one cycle ? Or is it anything else?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but 2W would be an average quantity.

Comment: A watt = 1 Joule per second.  Two watts means it is using two joules per second.

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of circuit you are asking about? Something like a microcontroller will have a power use that increases with the clock frequency, however, 100 Hz is a very low frequency for a microcontroller so people so far are answering a different question...

Answer (score 6):

Power is energy per time. It is up to you to define a time interval.

But usually we are talking about **mean** or **effective** power of a sine wave, which defines the time interval to be one or multiple full periods of the sine.

Answer (score 4):

An average power of 2 watts means 2 joules of energy per second. If you sub-divided this up into smaller time slots (i.e. 10 ms thus corresponding to a 100 time slots per second) the energy would be 0.02 joules per 10 ms. This is still a power of 2 watts because 0.02 joules divided by 0.01 seconds = 2 watts.

Answer (score 3):

Full wave Rectifiers are one way to produce 100 Hz from 50Hz but this can be done in microwatts. So power and frequency do not need to be relevant but might for some motor.

Power “may” be measured;

- in Zero Time as a sample
- or an Average , or a Peak or RMS value
- or in complex form X+jY  or Real, and Reactive
- or Apparent power the hypotenuse of the above
- or in some trig form A (cos wt)+B
- or estimated average power
- or true RMS power as DC power = RMS AC power

**Power has no Units of time**, unless  as additional information to compute Energy in watt-hours [Wh] or watt-seconds = Joules [J]

Answer (score 2):

i recall using a 9 amp Power Driver for MOSFET gates. The shoot-thru charge, during the 10 nanoseconds of internal slewing of control voltage, was rated in nanoCoulombs. Assume this was 5amps (mid-rail) for 10 nanosecond, or 50 nanoCoulombs. At 15 volts on the IC, the energy was 750 nanoJoules per transition, either going-positive or going-negative.
Thus a complete cycle was 1.5 microJoules. We used 0.1uF bypass caps, with 1cm leads, on the breadboards, and tolerated the constant 0.5 volt rail sag and the scary ringing.

At 1,000,000 cycles per second (Hertz) the internal power dissipation was 1.5 watts.

You could buy these parts in DIP (and 1.5 watts is a LOT of power, for a DIP) or buy a TO-220 with a 1cm by 2cm copper tab you could BOLT to a heatsink.

I (and my team) quickly learned to only use the TO-220 in our prototypes, with a small fan pushing air onto the hot tab.